# Can't connect to SQL Server using the configuration manager

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

After installing sql server I can't seem to connect to the server. I found a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088151/how-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server-management-studio).

However, when I open SQL Server Configuration Manager and Click on SQL Server Services there aren't any services there!

So how can I find my server name?

P.S. when I enter the server name `.\sqlexpress` it doesn't connect.

Comment: Was it SQL Server Express that you installed?

Comment: Does it show an error ? If so, What's the error message ?

Comment: IF SSCM sees no services, there's a good chance something went wrong during the installation. Could you somehow have prevented adding any services? Might be worth it to try and re-install everything, taking notes (perhaps screenshots as well) of every step of the setup process to later be able to provide additional details when asked.

Comment: Andriy M  I try reinstall, but nothing change. i add link on screenshots [link](http://www.foto-me.ru/v.php?id=b42c0078e9e40a25703fda4364a40a99)  i don't know what to do, because this sql server on my computer doesn't install, there were problems with Visual Studio 2008,  but on other computer install, but doesn't want to connect. please, give me advise how connect that sql server

Answer (score 0):

Open SQL Server Management Studio:

Server Type : Database Engine

Server Name : .

Authentication : Windows Authentication

Answer (score 0):

Are you have management studio. Then just simply open sqlserver. If try with first "Window Authentication" and not connect then connect with "SqlServer Authentication".

Or in "Server Name" option, just  which search your entire network sql server.

If you don't have sqlserver management studio, then you can connect with Visualstudio too.

It might be your firewall block or service is stopped.

[Connection to SQL Server Database inside Visual Studio 2012 C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269074/connection-to-sql-server-database-inside-visual-studio-2012-c-sharp)

Here is one usefull link to connect sqlexpress.

[How to connect to local instance of SQL Server 2008 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express)